# What am I doing wrong with this async function?

Tags: javascript, firebase

I am trying to learn/implement async functions, and I'm unsure why I am not able to get it to work. The 'users' in my async function are coming back undefined. However, the function that makes the database call works just fine.

```
 const getUsers = () => {
    const database = firebase.database()
    const users = database.ref('users');
    users.on('value', function(snapshot) {
        const users = []
        snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
          let user = childSnapshot.val();
          users.push(user)
        });
        return users
    });
  }

  async function generateRandomPotentialPartner() {
    try {
      const users = await getUsers();
      console.log(users)
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
    }
  }
```

Comment: getUsers isn't returning a promise. Wrap the contents of it inside a new Promise return, and return `users` as the resolve.

Comment: Also need to understand that a `return` in a callback *does not* return to the outer function.Your `getUsers` function has no return at all

Answer (score 1):

Use the promise version of `on()` instead of using the callback version and return that promise from `getUsers()` function.

Using the callback approach you are currently using, nothing is being returned at all since a return in a callback does not return to the outer function

```
const getUsers = () => {
  const database = firebase.database()
  const users = database.ref('users');
  // return the on() promise instead of using callback
  return users.on('value').then(snapshot => {
    const users = []
    snapshot.forEach(childSnapshot => {          
      users.push(childSnapshot.val())
    });
    return users
  });
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
 const getUsers = () => {
const database = firebase.database()
const users = database.ref('users');
users.on('value', function(snapshot) {
    const users = []
    snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
      let user = childSnapshot.val();
      users.push(user)
    });
    return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
      if(users.length == 0){
        reject("There are no users"); //--- Handle rejection
      }else {
        resolve(users);
      }

    });
  });
}
```

Your problem is that you are not returning Promises. Asynchronous Javascript is only about promises and chaining.